# Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator, localhost, ip

I am using *Retrofit2* to make network requests but the endpoint is locally on my machine.

So my base URL is
`private val BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000/"`, but it gives me this response
`Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:5000`

So I did some search and I found out that I need to use my local IP address as the following
`private val BASE_URL = "http:192.168.1.15//:8000/"`, but then I get this response
`Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=http://192.168.1.15//:8000/api/Home/RegisterShop}`

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: `http:192.168.1.15//:8000/` does not look like a valid URL.

Comment: Are you running the app on a device or an emulator?

Comment: If you're running the app on an emulator the base url should be `http://10.0.2.2:8000/`

Comment: I tried it both on the emulator and a real device it gives me the same errors.
I tried 10.0.2.2 but it's giving me `failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:8000`

Comment: @Onik the base url works fine. I just had to go to emulator settings and make it use default proxy. feel free to post this an answer and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using an *Android* emulator, the IP address of the host machine would be [10.0.2.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses).

So in your case it'd be `http://10.0.2.2:8000/`.

Answer (score 0):

Things you should do:

1. Use your local IP Adress instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1
2. While local, there is no SSL so you need to put to you manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

and to `<application>`:

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

After that it should work...
But keep in mind that if you go to prod, *CleartextTraffic="true"* is not a good idea.

Comment: thanks for your response. I already had the permissions and android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" already. any other ideas?

Comment: still, the same issue if I used my local IP address

Comment: Are you sure that the port is added correctly?
At the moment I am working on a REST Project with Android and Django Backend and the endpoint url would be for Django:

url=http://192.168.1.15:8000/api/Home/RegisterShop

Comment: yes I am sure. because this is the link I use on browser `http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand the issue.
How do you start you API Server? You need to bind it to your local address: e.g. 192.168.2.50 not to localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I tried to send the request using postman and it works just fine.. so this could be an android thing.. what do you think?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Your emulator needs to find the API at you LOCAL IP Adress.
For you Emulator 127.0.0.1 is the emulator not your PC!
You need to start the API correctly or try curl from your emulator - you'll see it will not work!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the local server address was `http://127.0.0.1:5000` (I used flask for my server, it runs on port 5000 by default)