# Problem in Implementing the API in android studio using localhost

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement a simple API to read data from localhost. The API is working fine in POSTMAN. However, when I implement it using RETROFIT, It doesn't load the data from localhost. I have made sure to check if the network is accepting response from 80 and it is fine. And I am also getting another error for recyclerview.

Here are these 2 errors:

> 1: RecyclerView  com.sarmadali.poetryapp  E  No adapter attached; skipping layout

and the other one is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference at com.sarmadali.poetryapp.Adapters.PoetryAdapters.getItemCount(PoetryAdapters.java:50)

Here's my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerViewPoetry;
    PoetryAdapters poetryAdapters;
    ApiInterfacePoetry apiInterfacePoetry;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InitializationMethod();

 apiInterfacePoetry.getPoetry().enqueue(new Callback<GetPoetryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetPoetryResponse> call, Response<GetPoetryResponse> response) {
                try {
                    if (response!=null){
                        if (response.body().getStatus().equals("1")){
                            SetAdapter(response.body().getPoetryData());
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Failure", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetPoetryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Failure Failure", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

 private void InitializationMethod(){

        recyclerViewPoetry = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPoetry);

        //initializing apis
        Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getClient();
        apiInterfacePoetry = retrofit.create(ApiInterfacePoetry.class);
//        poetryModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void SetAdapter(ArrayList<PoetryModel> poetryLists){

        poetryAdapters = new PoetryAdapters(this, poetryLists);
        //set layout manager
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerViewPoetry.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerViewPoetry.setAdapter(poetryAdapters);

    }
}
```

ApiClient.java

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static Retrofit retrofit=null;

    public  static Retrofit getClient(){

        if (retrofit==null) {

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.10.7/PHPPoetryApis/")
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

PoetryAdapters.java

```
public class PoetryAdapters extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PoetryAdapters.ViewHolderClass>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<PoetryModel> poetryList;

    //constructor
    public PoetryAdapters(Context context, ArrayList<PoetryModel> poetryModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.poetryList = poetryModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderClass onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        //inflating the layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.poetry_list_view_design, null);
        return new ViewHolderClass(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderClass holder, int position) {

        //set all the data

        holder.poetName.setText(poetryList.get(position).getP_Name());
        holder.p_Poetry.setText(poetryList.get(position).getPoetry());
        holder.dateTime.setText(poetryList.get(position).getDate_Time());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return poetryList.size();
    }



    //viewholder class created
    public class ViewHolderClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView poetName, p_Poetry, dateTime;
        Button btnUpdatePoetry, btnDeletePoetry;
        public ViewHolderClass(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            poetName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPoetName);
            p_Poetry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPoetry);
            dateTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatenTime);

            btnUpdatePoetry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
            btnDeletePoetry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATED**

Change in enqueue method:

```
apiInterfacePoetry.getPoetry().enqueue(new Callback<GetPoetryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetPoetryResponse> call, Response<GetPoetryResponse> response) {

                try {

                    if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getStatus().equals("1")) {
                            Log.e("Status Poetry", response.body().getStatus());

                            ArrayList<PoetryModel> poetryData = response.body().getPoetryData();
                            if (poetryData != null) {
                                SetAdapter(poetryData);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Poetry data is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "API call was not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Failure", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetPoetryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Failure Failure", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Here the first check successful and the toast response is "record available" as set in the API

> if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null)

and the second one is

> if (response.body().getStatus().equals("1"))
> it also returns 1 in log means record is available.

and this one

> poetryData != null

is null because of this returning null.

> response.body().getPoetryData()

There isn't any network related issue here i think.

I hope this helps in answering my question.

Comment: "Here are these 2 errors" -- the first is not a real error. The second one is. However, it is tied to code that is not shown in your question, such as `ApiClient` and `PoetryAdapters`.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated my question. see now.

Comment: Apparently, `response.body().getPoetryData()` is returning `null`.

Comment: [Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:5000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65264545/3290339)

Comment: After adding port with the ip i got this: failed to connect to /192.168.10.7 (port 8000) from /192.168.10.2 (port 53056) after 10000ms

Comment: @CommonsWare i have updated my question please see now.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this by Comparing the structure of the API response JSON with the structure of my GetPoetryResponse class. The class structure doesn't match the JSON structure including field names and hierarchy. These mismatches led to Gson being unable to deserialize the JSON properly hence I was getting the null exception from **GetPoetryResponse()**. Now everything is according to the order.